# Make sure duplicates does not happen while automatic indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many feeds that are flowing in to my server.

```
Example document is as follows -
{
"company" : "sony",
"size" : "10X",
"name" : "Kakhee pants",
"color" : "red"
}
```

The fields "company" and "name" is to be kept unique. That is I do not want 2 documents with the same company and name but different color and size.
How i can establish this in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best strategy for this would be to create docID based on value of these three fields.
For instance , for this document -

```
{
"company" : "sony",
"size" : "10X",
"name" : "Kakhee pants",
"color" : "red"
}
```

Make the docID as sony+Kakhee_pants+red
And then abstract the size and color to attribute array.

```
{
  "company": "sony",
  "name": "Kakhee pants",
  "color": "red",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "size": "10X",
      "color": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now , when you are inserting documents make an [upsert](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts)
When you are indexing the document if document does not exist and you are updating attributes field when document do exist.